# Several calls to DoModal() function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, modal-dialog

I have a problem with DoModal() function when I try to call more than once.
How can I make several calls to DoModal() function?
I leave below the code I'm using:

```
if((dlg.DoModal()) == IDOK){
            iplMirror(img2,imgSAVE,0); 
            cvSaveImage(dlg.m_ofn.lpstrFile,imgSAVE); 
}
if((dlg.DoModal()) == IDOK){
            iplMirror(img2_2,imgSAVE_2,0); 
            cvSaveImage(dlg.m_ofn.lpstrFile,imgSAVE_2);
}
```

I'm saving 2 images with an function from openCV library and in the first "IF" the function works fine, but in the second "IF" it generated an error.
Someone could help me with this? I will thank.

Comment: So you are asking about method of object `dlg` without a word about what it is exactly.

Comment: What error did it generate? Is dlg a CFileDialog?

Comment: Have you tried dlg.GetFileName()? Is one of those functions you're calling doing potentially something funny with the buffer? This may shed some light: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43xtah3y.aspx